# Cannot figure out how to center multiple links in a navigation bar using CSS

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries, centering

I'm trying to center Link 1, Link 2, and Link 3 in the following page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVWAy.png

Here is the relevant bit of html:

```
<a class="logo" href="#"><p>Logo</p></a>

<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="link" href="#"><p>Link 1</p></a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#"><p>Link 2</p></a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#"><p>Link 3</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

and here's the css:

```
.link
{
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #123456;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0;

}

.nav
{
    margin-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I've tried every combination of things that I can think of.

To be specific, I'm trying to center the links such that they are all evenly spaced out along the nav bar.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

jsfiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/B362m/

Comment: please provide `jsfiddle`

Comment: @DoanCuong  http://jsfiddle.net/B362m/   -- if it isn't already, narrow the result window until it snaps to mobile settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.nav
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B362m/2/)

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda a lot of css you've got there. (Consider using shorthand for your seperate margin values?) Two things..

1) if your elements are inline-block, then you can set text-align on the parent to move stuff to the left/center/right accordingling.

2) Your links are already just text, so is there a specific reason why you've set them to inline-block rather than just inline? Not that it makes a big deal.. setting inline-block will allow you to set padding and boost the clickable area.

Anyway... this should align your links:

```
.nav {
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to get the look you're going for.

Try this:

```
.nav
{
    margin:auto;
    width: 80%; 
    display:table;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav li
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B362m/3/)